# sshd log contains "pam_unix authentication failure"

Tags: linux, ssh

I am getting the following error messages in my Linux machine.

```
sshd[9287]: message repeated 2 times: [ error: PAM: Authentication failure for root from 172.16.2.1]  
sshd[9287]: Received disconnect from 172.16.2.1: 11:  [preauth]  
sshd[9312]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for root from 172.16.2.1  
sshd[9315]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=172.16.2.1  user=root
```

this happens often and my log is full of this error message. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you stuck?

Comment: So far changed sshd_config file, no positive results

Answer (score 6):

Someone is trying to brute-force the password for your `root` user.
(It doesn't matter if password login is prohibited for it — they can still try, they'll just fail every time.)

**You normally won't want to suppress these log messages**; they can be useful information when someone does manage to break into your system at some point.
<sub>(Though you'll need append-only off-site backups of the log to be safe in that case.)</sub>

You can use a log aggregation system (like Logstash or Graylog) to filter off these messages into a different view to deal with them separately, or you can `grep -v '[Aa]uthentication failure]' /var/log/syslog | less` to filter them out when manually viewing the log.

You can also report the brute-force attempts to the operator of the source system, but that's usually tilting at windmills.
<sub>(Note that you're seeing the private network address of your NAT gateway (172.16.2.1), so you'll need to check the gateway for the actual external address.)</sub>

The usual mitigations are just pre-filtering and obfuscation:

- Make sure password-based login for the `root` user is disabled in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

  ```
  PermitRootLogin without-password

  # or
  PermitRootLogin no

  # or (at the very end of the file, since `Match` extends until the next `Match` or end of file)
  Match User root
  PasswordAuthentication no
  ```
- Configure your firewall to block connections to the SSH port from IP ranges that you don't normally connect from (either as a whitelist or a blacklist),
- Possibly change the SSH port to a non-standard one (though that can cause compatibility issues with software that doesn't support custom ports).

Comment: Hello @n.st I'm in a reverse situation at present, from my static IP these attacks are being made to some other webserver (they have notified me about it). What can I do to find where is the problem in my servers? Looks like someone has breached into my servers and doing the attacks. The last possible solution I can think of is to re-install all of my On-Prem servers and start from scratch. I'm using Ubuntu 18 in all of them.

Comment: @SunilKumar Your server has been hacked. Solution: 1. `cat /var/log/auth.log | grep -i "accept"`. Also check `auth.log.1`, etc. You will see what users have been connected. Find the suspicious one. In my case it was `vsftp` (password was brute-forced). 2. Find all processes of this user: `pa -u vsftp`. 3. Kill them: `sudo kill -9 processIdHere`. 4. Del user folder: `sudo deluser --remove-home vsftp`. 5. Change ssh port. 6 Disable password ssh authentication.

Comment: Hello @TitanFighter thanks for your suggestion, I have noted down all the steps for reference in future. Since, this was one month back and didn't found a way to fix it, I have re-installed OS from scratch in all servers and yes I have disabled password authentication after installation, only ssh is allowed from a different port. Thanks again.